# Awkwardly formed linear spaces exercise

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across such an exercise:

> Let $V$ be a linear space over $K$ such that $\dim V = n$. Show that for any $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_m$ with $ m > n + 1$ there exist
>   $a_1, \dots, a_m \in K$ such that 
>   $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \triangleright \alpha_i = 0_V$
>   and
>   $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i = 0_K$

But then the answer is trivial: it is $a_1 = \dots = a_m = 0$. What could've this exercise been meant to be?

Comment: Maybe the coefficients sum up to $0_K$ and not $0_V.$ Still your example solves it. Maybe the coefficients are not all zero? This would give a more interesting exercise. I don't know. Just a thought.

Comment: @Marko Absolutely, that must be what was meant. Then it becomes a somewhat funny exercise.